# DjangoUnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x93 PDF file is not saving

Tags: django, encode

This is my piece of code here in an API:

```
    result = StringIO.StringIO()
    pdf_template = get_template(
        "submit_quotation.html").render(Context(ctx))

    result = StringIO.StringIO()
    pisa.pisaDocument(
        StringIO.StringIO(pdf_template), dest=result)
    attachment = result.getvalue()
    notification_template = NotificationTemplate.objects.get(
        notification_event='submitquote')
    print 'bro'
    Communication.objects.create(
        entity_id=obj.id,
        entity_name='quotation',
        entity_type=ContentType.objects.get(model='quotation'),
        # receivers=user_ids,
        subject=notification_template.subject,
        # to=user_ids[0],
        content=notification_template.content,
        communication_type=1,
        attachment=attachment
    )
```

and here I am creating a PDF file and want to save it in a `FileField` in model

Model is

```
 class Communication(Timestampable):
   attachment = models.FileField(
    upload_to=file_path,
    blank=True,
    null=True,
)
```

But getting this error

```
   DjangoUnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x93 in 
   position 10: invalid start byte. You passed in '%PDF-1.4\n%\x93......
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: i m new to stack overflow and sorry and will remember this thanks...@halfer